# Prove/ Disprove: $\{(x,y,xy)^T\in \mathbb{R}^3 : -1<x, y<1 \}$ is a 2d sub-manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Given the set $S$ 
$$\{(x,y,xy)^T\in \mathbb{R}^3 : -1<x, y<1 \}$$
Prove/ disprove it is a 2d sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We have previously only shown that $\{(x,y,f(x,y))^T\in \mathbb{R}^3\}$ and a sphere are sub-manifolds. My understanding is too shaky however to formalize a proof. I have found out that open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (German Wikipedia) are sub-manifolds, which $S$ is, but I have no idea how to formalize a proof for $S$ being a sub-manifold.

Comment: $S$ is not an open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.However, as a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ it is homeomorphic with the 2-manifold $(-1, 1) \times (-1, 1)$ comprising the product of two open intervals - do you see why?

Comment: @RobArthan Why isn't S open? $x\in (-1,\infty)$ and $y \in (-\infty, 1)$?

Comment: It isn't open because any open ball around $(x, y, xy) \in S$, contains points $(x, y, xy+\epsilon)$ for small positive $\epsilon$ and $(x, y, xy+\epsilon) \not\in S$.

Comment: Hint: open subsets of manifolds are themselves manifolds (do you see why?).

Comment: @RobArthan ok, I still don't see the homeomorphism,  ($\frac{1}{x}$ isn't continuous...) or are you referring to the fact they are homeomorphic without actually finding the homeomorphism?

Comment: @SimoneRamello I think I do see why, but how does that help if S isn't an open set?

Comment: You've already proved that $\{(x,y,f(x,y)) \in {\Bbb R}^3\}$ is a sub-manifold, call it $M$. Then $S = M \cap (-1, +\infty) \times (-\infty, 1)$.  It is open in the subspace topology of $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give $S$ the subspace topology. Then check that the map $(x,y,xy)\mapsto (x,y)$ is a homeomorphism of $S$ onto $\{(x,y) : -1<x, y<1 \}$ and the latter is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$, so $S$ is, too.

Another way to do this is to check directly that $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb R^3:$

$M:=\{(x,y) : -1<x, y<1 \}$ is a dimension $2$ submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$, and you can check (as above) that  $f:M\to \mathbb R^3:(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,xy)$ is a homeomorphism of $M$ onto $S$, where $S$ has the subspace topology. It remains to check that $f$ is an immersion; that is, that $d_pf$ is injective, for $p=(x,y)\in M.$ But this is clear since the Jacobian matrix of $d_pf:T_pM\to T_{f(p)}\mathbb R^3$ is

$$\mathcal Jf(p)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0&1 \\ 
 y&x 
\end{pmatrix}$$